# What are the benefits of the new Marks and Spencer large image fade?

Tags: homepage, loading, page-layout

Marks and Spencer recently rolled out their new site. For those that haven't seen it, take a look, works well. http://www.marksandspencer.com/

Did you notice that the large image fills the screen at the beginning of the website load?

Why is this? What are benefits of doing this? Is it something to do with page load? design? or is a there a specific usable advantage of doing this?

Comment: One drawback I noticed is that the menus and functionality of the site are unavailable whilst I wait for them to load. Good question; I look forward to the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the main objective is to establish a **primary point of focus** with the full screen hero image and ensure the user observes the messaging (in this case the new look of the site).

Here are some examples of sites who do that

[image]

[image]

[image]

That said, the sudden change in design is very disconcerting and **can cause the user to lose focus** as there are  a number of new elements on the page and the user has to refocus again to define his point of focus and his potential next steps. Another down side is that the transition is not very smooth and due to the large site load, users with low bandwidth restrictions can be stuck between transitions.

Also as Bernhard rightly pointed out the lack of any other navigational aides in the initial load can confuse users about how to interact with the site.

Comment: Thanks @Mevin. Any chance you can provide the URLs for those examples you provided?